# I have to update a dataframe based on some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas I  am trying to update the column 'Text' based on the column `'Id'`.

the data i have is like this `[(1,'One'), (0, 'Zero'), (4,'Four'), (3, 'Three')]`
I also have some missing id's in the data, for those missing id's I have to leave it blank

original dataframe

```
Id  A   Text
 0  0      NaN
 1  1      NaN
 2  2      NaN
 3  3      NaN
 4  4      NaN
```

Final dataframe

```
 Id  A     Text
 0  0      Zero
 1  1      One
 2  2      NaN
 3  3      Three
 4  4      Four
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please format your DFs, so they are readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html): It will map elements corresponding to keys and values in the dictionary.

```py
li = [(1, 'One'), (0, 'Zero'), (4, 'Four'), (3, 'Three')]
df.Text = df.A.map(dict(li))
df
   Id  A   Text
0   0  0   Zero
1   1  1    One
2   2  2    NaN
3   3  3  Three
4   4  4   Four
```

When `arg` is a dictionary as in this case, values in `Series` that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to `NaN`.